# ActiveRecord- Inner Join two SQL tables + Where clauses

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two tables in MySQL and I would like to call a SQL query using an inner join and multiple Where clauses based on a form's input. I am aware that you can execute a raw SQL Query via ActiveRecord::Base.connection, but I'd like to learn how to do so using ActiveRecord objects. The schema for the two MySQL tables are like so:

```
Describe Options;

'VIN','varchar(45)','NO','PRI',NULL,''
'LEATHER','varchar(45)','YES','',NULL,''
'4WD','varchar(45)','YES','',NULL,''
'FOGLIGHTS','varchar(45)','YES','',NULL,''
'DVD','varchar(45)','YES','',NULL,''
'SURROUND','varchar(45)','YES','',NULL,''
```

and

```
Describe Inventory;
'VIN','varchar(30)','NO','PRI',NULL,''
'MAKE','varchar(30)','NO','',NULL,''
'MODEL','varchar(30)','NO','',NULL,''
'TYPE','varchar(50)','NO','',NULL,''
```

I would like to execute a SQL script like so:

```
Select Inventory.* from Inventory
INNER JOIN Options
ON Inventory.VIN = Options.VIN
WHERE Inventory.Make = "Toyota"
AND Options.Leather = "Yes";
```

My Ruby classes in ActiveRecord are like so:

```
 class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "Options"
 end

 class Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "INVENTORY"
 end
```

Again, I know that I can just input the query as a script, but I'd like to learn how to do it via Ruby best practices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change into this:

```
Inventory.joins("INNER JOIN Options ON Inventory.VIN = Options.VIN")
         .where("Inventory.Make = ? AND Options.Leather = ?", "Toyota", "YES")
```

In my opinion, I'd say that you have to change you table into `inventories` and `options` for model `Inventory` and `Option` so you don't need to use `set_table_name` in each model. It's about rails convention style code. Then you can see the model like this.

```
class Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :options, foreign_key: "VIN"
end

class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inventory, foreign_key: "VIN"
end
```

I hope this help you.